# MapStruct: How to map property from "java.lang.Object to "java.lang.String"

Tags: java, gson, dto, mapstruct, mapper

New to MapStrut; Object to String Error:

> [ERROR] /util/LicenseMapper.java:[11,23] Can't map property "java.lang.Object license.customFields[].value" to "java.lang.String license.customFields[].value". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.String map(java.lang.Object value)".

Code:

```
@Mapper
public interface LicenseMapper {
    List<License> jsonToDao(List<com.integrator.vo.license.License> source);
}
```

The vo.license contains List of CustomFields having property as

```
@SerializedName("Value")
@Expose
private Object value;
```

The Json has input for one field as object as it might come boolean or string or anything so i have mapped it into object. Whereas in dao layer has same field in String. (In custom mapper i just String.valueof but not sure how to achieve it using Mapstrut)

Can anyone tell me what settings are required in LicenseMapper to convert Object to String?

License Structure - Source and destination:

```
.
.
private String notes;
private Boolean isIncomplete;
private List<CustomField> customFields = null;
private List<Allocation> allocations = null;
```

Custom Field Structure in Source (removed gson annotations):

```
.
.
private String name;
private Object dataType;
private Object value;
```

---

Custom FIeld Structure in Destination

```
private String name;
private String datatype;
private String value;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use annotation @Mapping with expression

```
@Mapping(expression = "java( String.valueOf(source.getValue()) )", target = "value")
List<License> jsonToDao(List<com.integrator.vo.license.License> source);
```

UPDATE

```
@Mapper
public interface LicenseMapper {
LicenseMapper MAPPING = Mappers.getMapper(LicenseMapper.class);

List<License> entityListToDaoList(List<com.integrator.vo.license.License> source);

License entityToDao(com.integrator.vo.license.License source);

List<CustomField> customFieldListToCustomFieldList(List<*your custom field path*CustomField> source);

@Mapping(expression = "java( String.valueOf(source.getValue()) )", target = "value")
CustomField customFieldToCustomField(*your custom field path*CustomField source);
}
```

IN YOUR CODE

```
import static ***.LicenseMapper.MAPPING;

***
List<License> myList = MAPPING.jsonToDao(mySource);
```

Comment: Thanks for response but It is saying -> Unknown property "value" in result type java.util.List<com.integrator.snow.model.license.License>. Did you mean "empty"?

This value exists in List<CustomField> inside License class... How to mention that in expression

Comment: oh sorry. Try to replace String.valueOf(value) to String.valueOf(source.getValue() )

Comment: Let me try. But getValue is not present in License. It is present in License.customFields.value. and customFields is of type list

Comment: Tried this -> @Mapping(expression = "java( String.valueOf(source.customFields[].getValue()))", target = "value") but not able to fix.

Comment: Oh sorry i did a mistake

Comment: Great Man. It worked for me and even by your example i am ale to understand how things work as i was not able to get straightforward example for this scenario. Kindly remove snippet above that. 

One more thing if you can help. How to call this LicenseMapper in main code?

Comment: I prefer to create field in mapper like this : " LicenseMapper MAPPING = Mappers.getMapper(LicenseMapper.class); " This allow me to import static method import static ***.LicenseMapper.MAPPING and then i can use methods like that : List<License> myList = MAPPING.jsonToDao(mySource); I will add this to code

Comment: Thanks Nick. Marked it as answer

Answer (score 0):

U can do this :

@Mapping(target = "yourTarget", source = "yourClass.custField.value")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKtue.png)